# Difference in meaning due to comma

Tags: meaning, commas

- $1 with tax
- $1, with tax

What is the difference in meaning due to the comma?  I take the first to be the total is $1 and the second is $1 plus tax.

Comment: Difference?  They're both poorly constructed.

Comment: I agree, but it's a work thing so the distinction IS important.

Comment: They're both ambiguous.  It should be "$1 plus tax" or "$1 including tax".  In either of those the comma is optional.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference between those. Remember that the real language is spoken: try speaking those aloud and see what it buys you.

No matter the length of the pause that falls between *a dollar* on one side and *with tax* on the other, you cannot guarantee that everyone will understand what it is you mean.

Therefore, you should only say things where that doesn’t matter. For example:

- one dollar before tax
- one dollar plus tax
- one dollar after tax
- one dollar, not including tax
- one dollar, tax included

Any native speaker should be able to figure out which of those is which — and most non-native speakers, too, I’d imagine.

Comment: Bingo for answer but i will say, I disagree with the conclusion from your first 2 prems: when spoken aloud, *if* you add context. As they are, they are both fragments. "It is one dollar, with tax" (no stress) "It is one dollar with tax" (stress *with*, and in the case that you stress it -- there would be no comma). I feel that such responses would have dichotomous meanings?